How can the public properly understand climate change when it is exploited for speculation on the food price?
During the Easter period the news were busy explaining to the public that the high cost of chocolate was due to climate change. After the spending peak of Easter passed the tone suddenly changed. The news outlet didn't even seem to bother about the contradiction between news that came out in a short timespan.
An internet search with the keywords "rising cocoa price" will retrieve many news like this one that blame climate change or El Niño, but fail to note that the majority of cocoa plantations are located in a corner of Western Africa due to low labour cost. When a crop is highly concentrated in one area it is normal to have some fluctuations, furthermore there is probably a drop because the area is overexploited. Most of the news retrieved via search engines are more or less behind paywalls, but they all tell the same story with little difference.
The sample news came from an outlet that is paid by the British people therefore it is supposed to edit the news in their interest, rather than the interest of the private businesses. But it does not seem to be the case. If this is the attitude of the public broadcasters it is reasonable to imagine that the private one are no better or even worse. How can the public in this context get a proper understanding of the real problems related to climate change?

This is a Q for https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ at best.

Yeah, well, maybe it's not the public, but you.
Climate change manifestations and adaptations in cocoa farms: Perspectives of smallholder farmers in the Adansi South District, Ghana - ScienceDirect

Climate change can have huge consequences for cocoa farming and the livelihoods of communities in tropical Africa, although evidence of such effects is scanty. This study evaluated the perceptions of smallholder cocoa farmers on climate change manifestations and adaptations in the Adansi South District, Ghana.


The findings suggest the need for relevant policies to educate cocoa farmers on the effects of climate change, highlighting the risks and benefits, and prioritizing key adaptation options for sustainable cocoa production in Ghana.

Ivory Coast: cocoa industry devastated by rains | Africanews

Supplying around 40% of the world's cocoa, the Ivory Coast is the leading producer. But after exceptionally heavy rains this year, the country's cocoa warehouses are almost empty with producers expecting a harvest of between 3 to 4 times smaller than last year.


The west African country relies heavily on its cocoa production, with a fifth of the Ivorian population reliant on cocoa for their income.

Cocoa production in West Africa, a review and analysis of recent developments - ScienceDirect

Climatic change and increased land use for food crops will negatively affect the cocoa output in the long run.

Frontiers | Assessment of the impact of climate and non-climatic parameters on cocoa production: a contextual analysis for Cameroon

Furthermore, the long-run analysis indicates that temperature, rainfall, carbon dioxide emission, and land use are significant negative determinants of the yearly changes in cocoa output. We recommend government policy reforms which address access to land, subsidies/climate finance and improved production technologies to reduce greenhouse gas emissions and enhance farmers' adaptive capacities to climatic stressors.

Sure, I can totally see how chocolate companies would encourage you to "buy it while you can" around Easter time.  Good supply/demand manipulations.  And, yes, the press can be "in on it", to an extent.
Doesn't make your claims of conspiracy theories that there is no substance to, you know, "climatic variations having negative impacts on crops", any more insightful.

Trouble is that this does not explain why after Easter the tone changed.

Short term variation in demand. Economics 101. The long term trend, climate-driven, isn't actually all that great. That's what your question is about, right? climate-change tag and all that? I mean, if your question was about what the press might run as stories to benefit "friendly industries", then I'd have not answered. Or given a different answer.  And for what it's worth, seems to me the BBC often talks up British business.  Like when they got me to buy Peter Molyneux's (British dude) abysmal Black and White videogame.  Or when they regularly talk up middling British movies and musicians.

Your comment is too simplistic. Long term is also overpopulation and overexploitation of the resources. This is a worldwide trend, not something related to sudden price changes.
